# SQLite delete limit

Tags: sqlite, delete-row

The question is simple: Is there a limit on rows you can delete in SQLite.

I have a database 42 tables, one of the tables consists of 75000 rows. When I want to delete them, SQLManager in FF crashes.

So is there a limit on deleting rows in SQLite?

Comment: Did you try it using the `sqlite` tool? https://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html

Comment: No, but that wouldn't help. I have made a program that's going to handle the database file, and this to has to delete all the records. So I just wanted to ask: is there a limit on deleting rows in SQLite. If so, I need to find myself an other statement to excute :)

Comment: If you didn't try, how can you know it wouldn't help? What is the SQL you need to `DELETE`?

Comment: 'DELETE FROM licenses'. It is my program who has to delete them, not an other sqlite-tool, and since it can't, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Then please rephrase your question and ask if there is a bug in Firefox/SQLManager. The answer to your current question is "no".

Answer (score 3):

I've had *no* troubles deleting hundreds of thousands of rows in SQLite so, if it's a problem, it's not with the DBMS itself. It *may* be a problem with SQLManager but I'm not qualified to comment on that.

My suggestion would be to use the tools that SQLite provides (or your own code) rather than using some third-party product - that way, you'll *know* that any limitations you find (and I suspect, based on experience, that it won't be many) will be due to the product itself.